# Outlook for Mac - Keyboard shortcut to categorise an email?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just moved from windows where I could assign a keyboard shortcut to my categories (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc).

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard shortcut for this via

> System preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> app shortcuts.

However I can't seem to access the dropdown options of categories.
I can set a shortcut for "Categorise" but this does nothing.
I want to create a shortcut for

> Categorise -> "My Category here"

Would really appreciate any advice you could provide!

[Categories I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj2oz.png)
[Shortcuts I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lmnJ.png)

Comment: "However I can't seem to access the dropdown options of categories". Choose Microsoft Outlook.app in the Application drop-down menu. Then type the name of your category in the "Menu Title" field.(If I had a Outlook category named "Test", then you need to enter "Test")

Answer (score 2):

I literally just had the same dilemma and had to figure it out myself after not finding a decent answer. Try entering the full menu path separated by -> e.g.:

Messages->Categorise->Action Required

Note that your menu structure may differ slightly to mine depending on your system locale and version of Outlook. I am from Australia and we use the -ise instead of -ize spelling (recognise instead recognize).

Answer (score 2):

See also this [answers.microsoft.com answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-the-shortcut-to-assign-a-category-to-an-e/d036b735-c496-44a9-bb8d-510504bd4298).
You can add a keyboard shortcut under Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts ; `select Microsoft Office.app`.  Simply use the category name as the **Menu Title:** in the keyboard shortcut. You don't need the menu path.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer! No need for the path. System I use this on: mac OS Catalina v10.15.7 (19H1419) & Microsoft Outlook for Mac v16.54 (21101001).